# GenericUDF of hive execute twice on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-hive, spark-hive

Hello i facing some problem with creating genericUDF of hive and register as temporary function but when i call it its call twice see code given below

i create a genericUDF with following code

```
class GenUDF extends GenericUDF{
   var queryOI: StringObjectInspector = null
   var argumentsOI: Array[ObjectInspector] = null

 override def initialize (arguments: Array[ObjectInspector]):ObjectInspector = {
   /*if (arguments.length == 0) {
     throw new UDFArgumentLengthException("At least one argument must be specified")
   }
   if (!(arguments(0).isInstanceOf[StringObjectInspector])) {
     throw new UDFArgumentException("First argument must be a string")
   }
   queryOI = arguments(0).asInstanceOf[StringObjectInspector]
   argumentsOI = arguments*/
   println("inside initializeweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee")
   return PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector
  }

  override def evaluate (arguments: Array[GenericUDF.DeferredObject]):Object = {
    println("inside generic UDF::::::::::::::::::::::((((((((((((((((((((((((FDDDDDDDDDDDDD:")
    4.toString
  }

  def getDisplayString(children: Array[String]): String = {
    println("inside displayssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss")
      return "udft"
    }

}
```

And when i register it with following statement

```
 hiveContext.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION udft AS 'functions.GenUDF'")
```

and when i call this function with following command

```
select udft()
```

it will execute the print statement in evaluate body twice.

Comment: you are running your code with --master local[2] ?

Comment: yess i set configuration for master as local[2] so its take 2 threads so can u please explain what is the reason behind execute UDF twice.

Comment: it's not executed twice, it's just being distributed among 2 cores, so each core execute is once per partition. It's one of the basics of distributed computing.

Comment: cool thankss i will set configuration for 1 core n then check it out.

Comment: But i have one question like if i have insert statement in my UDF then it will insert that record twice.

Comment: Why do you want to use one core ? What's the point of using a distributed computing framework if you want to running mono thread or mono core ?

Comment: i want to run it in distributed manner but i m facing one problem like in my udf i have insert query soo when it is going to execute its insert twice and i also put configuration as local[1] its print twice and when i run with local[4] it even print it twice . so i think its not dependent on cores.

Comment: I've never seen such a usage for udf to insert.

Comment: but i have use case like this bcoz i create my UDF at run time. and udf can have anything.

Comment: @eliasah Actually It can be called arbitrary number of times.

Comment: @zero323 So there is any solution to stop this?? like if in my function there is insert statement it will call twice or thrice.